Will ADO suggest resolved bugs while creating a new bug which is similar to previously resolved bugs?
In an Azure DevOps application, i am checking that while creating a new bug, based on the title or description of the bug, whether it filters and suggests any resolved bug which is similar to the new one.
I tried, but I am not getting it. I just want to know whether Azure team will be releasing a similar kind of feature as I stated above or not.

I don't think that kind of functionality is available in Azure DevOps.

As Rui mentioned, Azure DevOps does not currently offer a built-in feature that suggests similar resolved bugs when creating a new bug based on the title or description. For now, if you think this feature would be beneficial, you can suggest it to the Azure DevOps team via their feedback portal. Also once check - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/add-to-bugs-exploratory-testing?view=azure-devops#add-your-findings-to-a-bug

Has Arko answered your question? Alternatively, do you have code that is supposed to search for bugs, that you want this question to resolve? If the latter, could you include an example of the code and how it isn't working.
